# How to generate a chart using iTextSharp C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pdf, itext

I have been working on a MVC ASP.NET project using C# Visual Studio 2012, and I have to create a PDF report with charts (pie, bars etc). For the other reports in project I have used iTextSharp (to generate pdf). Can I use iTextSharp to create PDF with charts? How? Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Follow this link : http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/115/microsoft-chart-controls-to-pdf-with-itextsharp-and-asp-net-mvc

Comment: While @SaurabhSrivastava's comment is correct, just a note. This will rasterize the chart. Meaning it's an image. If you zoom in in Acrobat, it will get fuzzy as it's not stored as a vector like you might expect shapes and text to be in a PDF.

Comment: thank you both for your interest and help.

Comment: @SaurabhSrivastava, would you be so kind and explain how to include the Chart class from your link, I mean `var chart = new Chart` for example?

Comment: Already given in that link like that : `var chart = new Chart
  {
    Width = 300,
    Height = 450,
    RenderType = RenderType.ImageTag,
    AntiAliasing = AntiAliasingStyles.All,
    TextAntiAliasingQuality = TextAntiAliasingQuality.High
  };`

Comment: @SaurabhSrivastava, thank you again. Maybe my question is a little bit confusing. I mean the code doesn't recognize the Chart class, I have to include a namespace in `using` part. I want to know what namespace I should use for the class `Chart`.

Comment: You have to use these namespaces : `using System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting;
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using PDFCharting.Models;
using Color = System.Drawing.Color;
using Font = System.Drawing.Font;`

Comment: it works, everything is fine :) But I didn't find a way to set coordinates for the chart, to position left or right of the page (the whole chart). Please help if you can!

Comment: Follow these two links : http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/87/itextsharp-working-with-images       & http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/88/itextsharp-drawing-shapes-and-graphics

Comment: great, many thanks! But I have to create two series with two coordinate systems on the same chart and also to add their own table to the chart. How to do that? Please help!